# Retrieving JSON from a web URL

Tags: json, web-services, biztalk, biztalk-2009

This may be a terribly uninformed question, brace yourself. A company I'm working with has given an 'API' that I can use to access orders, however, there are only two real commands, getorders and getorderdetails. These commands are put in the format of `www.server.com/path/to/the/orderapi/getorders/UniqueKey/`

If I go to that web address, I'm prompted for a username and password, and once authenticating, get presented with a page of JSON formatted order details, contained in the body of the html page. I would like a service to check this information and create orders in our CRM based on it, is there an obvious way to access it without the browser/client interaction?

**Update:** We intended to Use BizTalk to consume this resource but after a bit of research and experimenting have decided to use a different service (WDSL), mainly because BizTalk doesn't seem to have terribly great support for Restful webservices. If anyone with more knowledge of the subject would like to chime in that's fine by me.

**Update 2:** Noticed that (a since deleted) thread on stackoverflow is basically a feedback thread of biztalk 2009-r2, and one of the requests is support for restful web services, so I don't think there is a graceful solution for restful services in BizTalk 2009.

Comment: BizTalk 2013-R2 supports JSON & RESTful services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your language of choice, along with some library that speaks HTTP, and start hacking away?

In PHP, you'd use the build-in cURL library to make the HTTP requests.  You'd grab the JSON data, run it through json_decode() to create native PHP datatypes, and then operate on them at will, doing whatever you need to do to create orders in your CRM.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Any ideas of where to look if I wanted to accomplish this task in Biztalk, since that's what our company wants to use for most integration?

Comment: I don't know anything about BizTalk, sorry.  You'll have to read up on it, and figure out how best to hook in.